# Call lower-level system commands from C++

Tags: c++, linux, system-calls

What I am trying to do (and I realize this will be non-portable code and `std::cout` could do it better) is replace the `std::cout` function with my own.  Basically, the reason we have been assigned to do this is to get more familiar with running system calls on a Linux operating system.

So from my research, it looks like what the system is calling when it outputs to the console is something along the lines of `write(1, "some string\n",12)`.  My problem now is that I can't figure out how to call this from my [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) code.  Using `System()` doesn't seem to work because you can't run that command in the shell.

Any ideas of how this could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `#include` the relevant header ([in this case `<unistd.h>`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write)), and call the function.

Comment: Ok so I feel sufficiently stupid for not trying that.  I had included that library to try running exec commands but didn't think of the fact I could just run the write command outright.  Thank you.